# what happens when we only malloc size of 1 int and not n ints in an array?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

it is usually the case that to dynamically allocate an array of n elements.
we do this:
`malloc(n*sizeof(int));`
but it seems to work even if we allocate only sizeof 1 int and then do this.

The below code works,so what is need to malloc 5*4 bytes? instead just malloc the 1st block

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
scanf("%d",a+i);

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
printf("%d\n",a[i]);

free(a);

}
```

Comment: Try using `i<50000`

Comment: "Seems to work" until you publish the code, when [Finagle's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finagle%27s_law) prevail.